# How to approach someone about stepping down from their position?

Tags: work-environment, conflict-aversion

A rather unfortunate situation has been developing at my workplace, which doesn't directly affect me but I would like to get involved because it looks like people are about to get hurt.

A dispute over a rather important issue (regarding this year's bonuses) has began between a department and upper management. In order to address the issue, said department has chosen a representative to talk with management to resolve said issue.

Unfortunately the person that has been chosen has the backbone of a paramecium. She is mediocre at her job, she's shy and doesn't have that good relationships with some people in upper management. Arguably, she is the second best choice from that group, since the best choice has a bit of an anger issue and might make things even harder.

I would like to get involved since there are a couple of people in that department that I am good friends with and possibly offer my help in the matter. I'm a good negotiator, I am a part of the upper management but in another department and I also am in good terms with this department's management. I believe it would be all around beneficial.

I was thinking of approaching the current group representative and asking them to step down for the reasons mentioned above.

**How can I tactfully approach this person and ask them to step down?**

*Another option would be to approach this department's staff directly and ask them to drop their current representative but it seems dishonest somehow and I would rather not ask multiple questions in one post.*

**Update**: I was actually approached this morning out of the blue and was asked my input on the situation (possibly someone from my work reads IPS). The answers below were very helpful in maneuvering the situation. It seems most of the department has little faith in their representative but they will go with her nevertheless since bringing the head of another department to an internal department discussion might be perceived as a threat to the current department head.

Although in reality this is not a corporate office, this is a hospital and the head of a department gunning for another department's head position is impossible.

Comment: You may seriously consider asking that over at The Workplace.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I imagine this is less about the workplace aspect of it and more about trying to find a tactful way to convince someone to let you handle something in their place.

Comment: @Cronax The expertise of the people over at the The Workplace would come in quite handy in such a situation, I would think.

Comment: The team selected her.  It is not up to you to replace her even if you convince her to step down.

Comment: The phrase "Not your circus, not your monkeys" comes to mind. Unfortunately, it's not your department, not your area of responsibility, and doesn't affect you professionally.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Thanks, I did consider the WorkplaceSE and if the answers here are not satisfactory, I will post there or request a migration of my question (if that's possible after answers have been added.

Comment: @Paparazzi The problem is that I can't stand by and watch these people get shafted because the best they got is that person. As I said I care deeply (long time friendship) with two people in that department.

Comment: @Xander While I can't provide an authoritative answer, this migrated post (opposite direction) seems to suggest that it's possible and answers migrate also: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/how-to-tell-other-people-that-my-job-is-only-a-job-to-me

Comment: It might be worth clarifying your actual position. You say that the dispute is between a department and upper management. You also say you are part of upper management but that you want to negotiate for the department. This sounds like a conflict of interest on the surface. Could you clarify - is the upper management that the dispute is with actual part of that department (its not what it sounds like from the description the upper management sounds separate from teh department)? ie its the lower members in the department conflicting with the higher members?

Comment: If the upper management is outside of the department could you clarify your relationship with them? You and they have both been described as upper management so it strikes me that from that description it sounds like you could influence the negotiation form the management side of things. I assume this is not the case or you wouldn't be asking this in this way but it might be worth clarifying this in the question.

Comment: @Chris I'd rather not be too specific but we're talking about me being head/director of a medical department (e.g. neurology, psychiatry etc.) and the chief of medicine in a hospital and the department that's negotiating are the nurses of another medical department (e.g. surgery). If I pick up this task, it would be against the hospital administration.

Comment: Bluntly you come across as having an almighty big opinion of yourself and a very low opinion of everyone else.  The fact that *you* don't think highly of this person is irrelevant : she was chosen by others and they do respect her.  On an IPS level I think the real problem you have is *your* attitude to other people.

Comment: @StephenG Thanks! Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. But when you have 15 people, 13 of which are afraid to step forward, 1 is hot-tempered and the other one is shy, then yeah I do consider myself above these two. Especially when the hot-tempered one asked me to represent them in the first place but I told her I would consider it due to the implications. On an IPS-level, I think you got a bit of a problem yourself there friend.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**How can I tactfully approach this person and ask them to step down?**

*I'd say don't do that...*

I'm assuming you only heard of the conflict after the department already picked a representative.

First of all, you go the chosen representative. You don't say she's not up to the job. You offer her your help with it.

> Hey, I just learned you're the representative for the department with regards to ... I only learned about the troubles now, but I've got some contacts here and there, and I think I might offer you some help if you feel you need it.

**she's shy and doesn't have that good relationships with some people in upper management.**

Maybe she sees it as a task that will allow her to build those relationships. As for the being shy part, tasks such as the one she's doing now are a good way to build confidence and learn to assert yourself better (trust me, I've been very shy myself, to the point of not daring to go collect a coffee cup my mom served a construction worker coffee in).

If she takes you up on your offer of help, give her all the support you can provide. **But make sure you don't take over her responsibilities.** She needs to learn to do such things herself, and she needs the connections. Having an ice-breaker is nice, having a rock to lean on is perfect. Having someone do everything for you isn't, it won't help you overcome any shyness or create new relationships.

If she accepts your help, feel free to let the department know (or even better, let her tell the department) that you're helping her, and that's its good to keep you in the loop.

If she refuses your help, let it go. **Don't go behind her back, don't tell the department you offered her your help.** Just make sure you're there if she gets in too much trouble and be approachable if she decides to come back on her decision to refuse your help.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I tactfully approach this person and ask them to step down?

Simple: **don't**. Why?

> In order to address the issue, said department has chosen a representative.

So, don't try anything to jump over her head, and stand in the front line.

**Offer your help and show your skills and capabilities** to ensure *the group (department)* an efficient clearing over the obstacle and reduce the risks of being overwhelmed by their strategy.

If the persons within this department think you can be of any help, they'll go back to you.

I would recommend that you list all the things that may be argued, bullet-list each point, and how you can help with each and every one of them. Then, give the list to the group, and ask them if they think it's a good idea, if it can be helpful, **if they want you to step in**. But *taking over her responsibilities* is not only rude, but will mostly be seen as arrogance.

Not to say going, alone, to the management and offer to take over...

**It's a department (read: all people together) battle, not an individual fight.**

---

At many workplaces, as I've seen many individuals who tried to take over others' responsibilities in their back, I can tell you it never went the right way...

**Last but not least: how would you feel if someone was doing this to you?**

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

> In order to address the issue, **said department has chosen a representative to talk with management** to resolve said issue.

A department has made a choice. You have no business asking that person to stand down. It's not only "not tactful", it's egregiously inappropriate to both the person chosen and the department that did the choosing. You are basically saying,

> Although this is none of my business, I feel I can handle this better than you can, so step aside (you paramecium), and let a real man (or woman) do the job.

If you are a good negotiator (as you claim), offer your help in a manner that doesn't undermine her confidence *in any way*. It's a hard thing to imagine, but here goes...

> Hey, Amy, I hear your department picked you to represent them in (x dispute.) Congratulations! If you want to practice your presentation, I'm happy to listen. But don't feel you have to take me up on it. I'm just offering to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

> She is mediocre at her job, she's shy and doesn't have that good relationships with some people in upper management

Yeah, don't say any of that.

What you should focus on is:

- **Availability:** Say you have some time on your hands. This can backfire a bit if it comes across that you don't do much in your day-to-day work and that gets back to management.
- **What you bring to the table:** Ideally something concrete, try to avoid implying that you're just better at negotiating than her.
- **Assistance:** Offer to assist, don't ask to replace her. She's unlikely to just step down, especially if you ask her, no matter how politely. Asking to replace her implies that she's incompetent - that's not a good message to send.

For example:

> Hey, I hear you're the representative ... . I thought I'd just tell you I'm available to assist if you'd like. I have some negotiating experience and I know management well, so I may be able to provide some valuable insight or contacts or you can just use me as a sounding board.

This may lead to her *letting you* take the lead eventually, but the more likely scenario is that she'll just ask for some help here and there.

If you want to force your way into the position, you may be able to use your contacts or seniority, but that's definitely going to burn bridges.